# combine two select queries?

Tags: mysql, query

I have two Mysql select queries:

```
select TTS.SSML, TTS_TAG.SORTID, TTS.VoiceId , TTS_TAG.TAGID FROM TTS 
left join TTS_TAG
on TTS_TAG.TTSID = TTS.TTSID 
where TTS.MID = 15

select max(TTS_TAG.SORTID) as maxsort from TTS_TAG
where TTS_TAG.TAGID = 1
```

I wish to combine both statements into one select statement, with the aggregate value added as a field in resulting output record?

The second aggregate select statement retrieves the maximum 'sort' for all records with the value 1 - if this second select yielded '3', then my desired record set would be:

```
# SSML, SORTID, VoiceId, TAGID, maxsort
'ssml data', '1', 'Geraint', '4', '3'
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you can add your second query as a sub select in your first query

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lennart!
A second sub select query within the first worked.

```
select TTS.SSML, TTS_TAG.SORTID, TTS.VoiceId , TTS_TAG.TAGID, 
(select max(TTS_TAG.SORTID) from TTS_TAG
where TTS_TAG.TAGID = 1) as maxsort
FROM TTS 
left join TTS_TAG
on TTS_TAG.TTSID = TTS.TTSID 
where TTS.MID = 15
```